# Render scrolling console

Tags: c++, modulo, vertical-scrolling

How can I render a scrolling console? Example:

Memory content (Frame 0):

```
Line 0 
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
```

Memory content (Frame 1):

```
Line 5
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
```

The corresponding screen output for Frame 1:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

The text is rendered to a framebuffer object (some wrappers involved):

```
auto N=r_console->rowsCountGet();
for(size_t k=0;k<N;++k)
    {
    glUniform3f(m_voffset_loc,0.0f,r_console->lineOffsetGet(k),0.0f);
    m_faces.dataSet(r_console->facesGet(k),GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    m_faces.draw();
    }
```

The rendering works for a trivial `Console::lineOffsetGet` that draws the memory content in the memory order: that is

```
auto n_rows=rowsCountGet();
return -static_cast<float>(2*k)/static_cast<float>(n_rows);
```

where `k` is the line in memory. I cannot find how to make `Console::lineOffsetGet` do the desired transformation (places the latest line at the bottom). It should map a line in memory `k`, to appropriate `y` coordinates. need to find a formula for computing the line on screen given the line in memory. I tried Tried

```
auto n_rows=rowsCountGet();
auto m_line_current<=n_rows? //If current line fits on the screen it is trivial
    k : (k+ (n_rows-(m_line_current-n_rows)%n_rows))%n_rows;
return -static_cast<float>(2*k)/static_cast<float>(n_rows);
```

where `m_line_current` increases for each line written to the console starting at zero. This works for two screen pages, but breaks at the beginning of the third one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I realized that there was a bug in counting the current line. Secondly, it is easier to do the modulo operation in the `facesGet`. This way, there is no need for subtraction. The correct expression in that function is simply

```
base + n_cols*(k + m_line_current)%n_rows
```